# Netsuite / jQuery page flashes

Tags: jquery, netsuite

I am kind of just looking for suggestions on how to stop the page from flashing.

What I mean by this is we have a table for a shopping cart that is generated by NetSuite and we have to completely change the the table with jQuery to get the look and feel that we have written styles for.

So it basically flashes with the "stock" look and feel and then once the jQuery executes it changes the table to our look and feel. Open to any and all suggestion on how stop it from flashing the "stock" cart.

We have tried using display:none; on the table and then at the end of the jQuery script showing the table and this seemed to reduce the file that it shows the old table but it is still visible for a second.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Set `display: none` on the CSS and it will not display initially.

Comment: It's difficult to provide an answer without looking at any of your code, perhaps a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but we have tried adding that above all stylesheets but nothing. 

Yeah i know this is hard to answer without looking at it but there is no way i could replicate the beast of NetSuite in a Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use a modal window to hide it in the background maybe.